# ORA-01017: invalid username/password error with oracle express:21.3.0-xe container

Tags: docker-compose, sqlplus, oracle-xe

I am using MAC book with apple M1 chip, and I am using [Colima][1] to run the oracle container over M1 chip.

I have a requirement to run integration test cases over the oracle container. And I am trying to create oracle container using service defined in docker-compose.yaml file.

I am able to start the container successfully but I am not able to login from the SQL Developer tool installed on my machine.

I am getting authentication error:

> Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

The surprising part in this problem is, if I explicitly bring up the container using following `docker run` command then, the DB login works properly with the SQL Developer tool, but it fails while running the container using compose file and `docker compose up` command.

Below the docker command which I am using to bring up the container and I am able to login to the DB using username "SYS" and password "secret".

```
docker run --name devdb -p 1521:1521 -p 5500:5500 -e ORACLE_PWD=secret container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:21.3.0-xe
```

And, below the docker-compose.yaml file which is causing database login problem.

```
version: '3'
services:
  oracle:
    image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:21.3.0-xe
    hostname: oracle
    container_name: oracle
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
      - 5500:5500
    environment:
      - ORACLE_PWD:secret
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/startup:/opt/oracle/scripts/startup
```

Below are the oracle server start up logs, where you can see the database server started successfully without any errors:

```
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container oracle  Created                                                                                                                           0.1s
Attaching to oracle
oracle  | Starting Oracle Net Listener.
oracle  | Oracle Net Listener started.
oracle  | Starting Oracle Database instance XE.
oracle  | Oracle Database instance XE started.
oracle  |
oracle  | The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
oracle  | #########################
oracle  | DATABASE IS READY TO USE!
oracle  | #########################
oracle  |
oracle  | Executing user defined scripts
oracle  | /opt/oracle/runUserScripts.sh: running /opt/oracle/scripts/startup/ddl.sql
oracle  |
oracle  | Table created.
oracle  |
oracle  |
oracle  | 0 rows deleted.
oracle  |
oracle  |
oracle  | 1 row created.
oracle  |
oracle  | DONE: Executing user defined scripts
oracle  |
oracle  | The following output is now a tail of the alert.log:
oracle  | Starting background process CJQ0
oracle  | 2023-04-03T19:29:19.672431+00:00
oracle  | CJQ0 started with pid=63, OS id=424
oracle  | Completed: ALTER DATABASE OPEN
oracle  | 2023-04-03T19:29:21.170374+00:00
oracle  | ===========================================================
oracle  | Dumping current patch information
oracle  | ===========================================================
oracle  | No patches have been applied
oracle  | ===========================================================
oracle  | 2023-04-03T19:29:36.087762+00:00
oracle  | System State dumped to trace file /opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_cjq0_424.trc
oracle  | 2023-04-03T19:30:03.688697+00:00
oracle  | XEPDB1(3):TABLE AUDSYS.AUD$UNIFIED: ADDED INTERVAL PARTITION SYS_P360 (3199) VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2023-04-04 00:00:00')
```

I tried removing the hostname, containerName and custom start up script configuration, but it did not help. I also tried the default password "**CHANGE_ON_INSTALL**" with SYS username but it did not work.

What is causing the authentication failure?

Do I need to explicitly provide tnsnames.ora or any other configuration while using docker-compose commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was able to login to the database while running the container with `docker run` command, without providing the SID name. So, I assumed, there is no need to provide SID name with `docker-compose` as well.

But, that was the main root cause behind the login issue. I provided the SID name in `docker-compose` file as mentioned below, and I am able to login the the database using **username : SYS**, **password : secret** and **SID : XE**.

Please refer below docker compose file for your reference.

```
oracle:
    image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:21.3.0-xe
    hostname: oracle
    container_name: oracle
    environment:
      - ORACLE_SID=XE
      - ORACLE_PWD=secret
    ports:
      - "1521:1521"
      - "5500:5500"
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/startup:/opt/oracle/scripts/startup
```

Comment: Oracle documentation says "The ORACLE_SID for Express Edition is always XE and cannot be changed, hence there is no ORACLE_SID parameter provided for the XE build."
Probably your ORACLE_SID env parameter is not taken into account, then it should not be what solved your problem.
Source : https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/README.md

Comment: @Nico that might be the possible reason. But I tried creating oracle with a different service name by providing the configuration in application.properties file of spring application and I was able to create a new service with a name other than XE.